# How to get SLURM task ID in program

Tags: slurm

I'm running `srun -n 100 python foo.py`. Inside the python script how does it find out which task number/id/rank it is? Is there an environment variable set?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at `man srun` or `man sbatch` for a list of environment variables. `$SLURM_PROCID` might be the one you need.